Importing CSV into GnuCash, but my bank doesn't have separate withdrawal and deposit column
I'm just getting started with GnuCash, and trying to manage a fairly simple account (Max 5 transactions each month).
I exported my transaction history from my bank, and the CSV they provide has an "Amount" column that is either positive or negative and a "type" column that is "Deposit" or "Withdrawal" -- but GnuCash wants "Deposit" and "Withdrawal" in separate columns.
I know I could just edit the file to move the Deposits and Withdrawals to separate columns, but is there a straightforward way to force GnuCash to work with the columns that I have?

I'm not sure whether GnuCash can accept a different format, but the transformation required can be probably easily done in Excel. Consider asking in superuser.com about how to make the transformation.

I wound up using the QFX importer, but it frustrates me that the settings for CSV imports are so cryptic.

GnuCash V5 doesn't use Deposit/Withdrawal like earlier versions, it uses Amount which can be positive or negative. Test it in a sample file and if the signs in the ledger are reversed to what you expect use Amount(negated).
Post a sample csv file with a transaction for an example.
